# Mathtype problem

Tags: ocr

Requirement is to convert the scanned maths book's page to LaTeX but need a better software than InftyReader, please suggest ?

InftyReader is good for PDF conversion to LaTeX where PDF is created from Computer typing but the conversion accuracy is not good enough in case of scanned book pages.

Comment: What you want is to convert a book in LaTeX? Why not rewrite what you need only?